# What types of chemicals/ionic liquid could perform this type of separation?

Tags: ionic-compounds

[Ionic Liquids separation of oil and sand.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGDKxlW1ZoQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the video from PennState, Aron Lupinsky tells that he is working in the group of Prof. Painter.

Combining these information, a **cursory search** furnishes the article

*Recovery of Bitumen from Low-Grade Oil Sands Using Ionic Liquids* by *Phillip Williams*, *Aron Lupinsky* and *Paul Painter*, published in 
*Energy Fuels*, **2010**, *24*, 2172–2173
([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ef901384s)).

On the first page of the article, it is mentioned that a mixture of toluene and 1-butyl-2,3-dimethylimidazolinium tetrafluoroborate, $\ce{[bmmim][BF4]}$, was used for the extraction.